# SPI interface question

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I was attempting this problem and I could not finish it.

I found the maximum frequency which was 67% as I divided 8 by 12(information bits/total bits), but I am having trouble finding the maximum utilization. The answer is 80%. I believe to find the utilization, you would divide the total packets per second over the total bits. To do that, I multiplied 300k with 0.67 and divided that number by 12. Can anyone explain to me where I went wrong?

> Suppose a throughput of 10,000 16-bit samples is still required for
>   the application, but the serial communication interface has the
>   following characteristics:
>
> - a total packet size of 12 bits: 8 bits of information and 4 bits of
>     overhead
> - does not require synchronization packets
> - a bandwidth of 300,000 bits per second
>
> What is the maximum efficiency and maximum utilization?

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: quiz actually. No idea what went wrong.

Comment: The link efficiency is simply total information bits / total link bits. The utilisation is different. That is the number of bits per second required / bits per second available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  For every 12 bits you transmit you must transmit 4 bits of overhead. So for every sample of 16 bits you must transmit 8 extra bits for a total of 24 bits per sample.  You're required to transmit 10,000 samples (per sec?) so that's 240,000 bits per second required.  You have a 300,000bps link so 240,000/300,000 = 80%.